# Create grouped proportions vector without losing rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am struggling to accurately explain the problem, but am able to accurately
demonstrate, I just want to find proportions within groups.

Using the following data :

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "large": ["L1" for _ in range(8)],
        "small": ["S1" for i in range(4)] + ["S2" for _ in range(4)],
        "who": ["D", "E", "F", "G"] + ["D", "E", "F", "G"],
        "amount": [1, 3, 2, 0, 3, 10, 2, 1],
        "total": [22 for _ in range(8)],
    }
)

df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "large": ["L2" for _ in range(8)],
        "small": ["S3" for _ in range(4)] + ["S4" for _ in range(4)],
        "who": ["D", "E", "F", "G"] + ["D", "E", "F", "G"],
        "amount": [0, 8, 1, 1, 5, 3, 4, 1],
        "total": [23 for _ in range(8)],
    }
)

df = pd.concat([df1, df2]).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Which outputs:

```py
In [82]: df
Out[82]:
   large small who  amount  total
0     L1    S1   D       1     22
1     L1    S1   E       3     22
2     L1    S1   F       2     22
3     L1    S1   G       0     22
4     L1    S2   D       3     22
5     L1    S2   E      10     22
6     L1    S2   F       2     22
7     L1    S2   G       1     22
8     L2    S3   D       0     23
9     L2    S3   E       8     23
10    L2    S3   F       1     23
11    L2    S3   G       1     23
12    L2    S4   D       5     23
13    L2    S4   E       3     23
14    L2    S4   F       4     23
15    L2    S4   G       1     23
```

I would like to compute the `(amount within large) / (total within large)`
for each of the `who`, so there will be some repetitions.

I can compute the values for each `who` as follows

```py
In [85]: df.groupby(['large','who']).agg('sum')
Out[85]:
           amount  total
large who
L1    D         4     44
      E        13     44
      F         4     44
      G         1     44
L2    D         5     46
      E        11     46
      F         5     46
      G         2     46
```

The `amount` column there is of interest.

Using `large_proportions` to represent the calculations i would have the
following (I've represented as fractions to make it clearer what's going on):

```py
   large small who  amount  total  large_proportions
0     L1    S1   D       1     22                  4/22
1     L1    S1   E       3     22                  13/22
2     L1    S1   F       2     22                  4/22
3     L1    S1   G       0     22                  1/22
4     L1    S2   D       3     22                  4/22
5     L1    S2   E      10     22                  13/22
6     L1    S2   F       2     22                  4/22
7     L1    S2   G       1     22                  1/22
8     L2    S3   D       0     23                  5/23
9     L2    S3   E       8     23                  11/23
10    L2    S3   F       1     23                  5/23
11    L2    S3   G       1     23                  2/23
12    L2    S4   D       5     23                  5/23
13    L2    S4   E       3     23                  11/23
14    L2    S4   F       4     23                  5/23
15    L2    S4   G       1     23                  2/23
```

## Summary

So the question is, given the original dataframe `df`, how to construct the
final output with the column `large_proportions`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `transform` in your calculation, so it remains with the original dimensions:

```py
df['large_proportions'] = df.groupby(['large','who'])['amount'].transform('sum') / df['total']

Out[32]: 
   large small who  amount  total  large_proportions
0     L1    S1   D       1     22           0.181818
1     L1    S1   E       3     22           0.590909
2     L1    S1   F       2     22           0.181818
3     L1    S1   G       0     22           0.045455
4     L1    S2   D       3     22           0.181818
5     L1    S2   E      10     22           0.590909
6     L1    S2   F       2     22           0.181818
7     L1    S2   G       1     22           0.045455
8     L2    S3   D       0     23           0.217391
9     L2    S3   E       8     23           0.478261
10    L2    S3   F       1     23           0.217391
11    L2    S3   G       1     23           0.086957
12    L2    S4   D       5     23           0.217391
13    L2    S4   E       3     23           0.478261
14    L2    S4   F       4     23           0.217391
15    L2    S4   G       1     23           0.086957
```

`Transform` will aggregate your values and repeat them so your results have the same length as the original series, even after the `groupby` take effect.

Answer (score 1):

The pyjanitor package offers a groupby_agg function that allows you to combine the result of pandas transform function back to the dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
import janitor

(df.groupby_agg(by=['large','who'],
                agg='sum',
                agg_column_name='amount',
                new_column_name='large_transformation'
                )

 #this gets your final output, transformation divided by total

.assign(large_transformation = lambda x: x['large_transformation'].div(x['total']))
)


   large    small   who amount  total   large_transformation
0    L1       S1     D     1      22       0.181818
1   L1        S1     E     3      22       0.590909
2   L1        S1     F     2      22       0.181818
3   L1        S1     G     0      22       0.045455
4   L1        S2     D     3      22       0.181818
5   L1        S2     E     10     22       0.590909
6   L1        S2     F     2      22       0.181818
7   L1        S2     G     1      22       0.045455
8   L2        S3     D     0      23       0.217391
9   L2        S3     E     8     23        0.478261
10  L2        S3     F     1     23        0.217391
11  L2        S3     G     1     23        0.086957
12  L2        S4     D     5     23        0.217391
13  L2        S4     E     3     23        0.478261
14  L2        S4     F     4     23        0.217391
15  L2        S4     G     1     23        0.086957
```

Comment: "The pyjanitor package" thank you for introducing this,I've accepted the other as it's more standard, and what I'm likely to use. I watched a talk (just now) on the janitor package though, it looks interesting.